# The number of ways in which a $9$-by-$9$ grid can be filled given some conditions.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, sudoku

[image]

How to find the number of ways in which the above $9$-by-$9$ grid can be filled using the digits $(1-9)$ (repetition is allowed) such that all of the following conditions are satisfied:

- Any $3$-by-$3$ grid is not totally empty.
- Any $3$-by-$3$ grid is not totally filled.
- Any $3$-by-$3$ grid must not contain repeated digits.
- Any row must not contain repeated digits.
- Any column must not contain repeated digits.
- There must not be any empty row.
- There must not be any row which is totally filled.
- There must not be any empty column.
- There must not be any column which is totally filled.

---

Here are examples of INVALID cases (according to the above conditions, respectively):

- An empty $3$-by-$3$ grid:

[image]

- A totally filled $3$-by-$3$ grid:

[image]

- Repeated digits in a $3$-by-$3$ grid:

[image]

- Repeated digits in a row:

[image]

- Repeated digits in a column:

[image]

- An empty row:

[image]

- A totally filled row:

[image]

- An empty column:

[image]

- A totally filled column:

[image]

---

Note that $C1,C2,C3,\dots,C9,R1,R2,R3,\dots,R9$ are positioned/attached to the $9$-by-$9$ grid to indicate that a rotated or transposed $9$-by-$9$ grid is considered as a different way (i.e. a rotated or transposed $9$-by-$9$ grid must be counted). Here are three examples of different VALID cases:

First example:

[image]

Second example:

[image]

Third example:

[image]

---

I saw similar question in this forum (sudoku problems), but those questions are not exact to this one.

Your help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: Have you tried using constraint programming?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I have no knowledge about that dear.

Comment: A reformulation that simplifies the conditions: Fill a 9 by 9 grid using the digits 0, 1, ..., 9 such that each row, column, and 3 by 3 grid contains at least one 0 and at least one positive integer with no positive integer repeated.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Thanks for commenting dear. What you have stated is exactly the case. Can you help me to solve it sir?

Comment: We have the following upper bound of the required number $N$ of ways. If a row has $k$ zeroes then $1\le k\le 8$ and there are ${9\choose k}$ ways to place them in the row and $\tfrac {9!}{k!}$ ways to fill the remaining $n-k$ cells with positive numbers. This give us in total $N_r=\sum_{k=1}^8 \tfrac {9!^2}{k!^2(9-k)!}=17209233$ possibilities to fill a row. Since we have $9$ rows, $N\le N_r^9\approx 1.324\cdot 10^{65}$. This bound can be improved if we take into account that the rows are not independent but cannot contain a common positive number in the same column.

Comment: @AlexRavsky That makes sense, thanks for it. I actually thought in different ways to solve the problem, no way worked. I believe you can give extra hints/useful formulas and then I will try to solve it and show you my answer for verification, can you please?

Answer (score 1):

We can improve the upper bound of the required number $N$ of ways from my [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613430/the-number-of-ways-in-which-a-9-by-9-grid-can-be-filled-given-some-condition?noredirect=1#comment7446303_3613430) as follows.

Consider the first column of the filled grid. Assume it has $k$ zeroes. Then $1\le k\le 8$ and there are ${9\choose k}$ ways to place them in the column and $\tfrac {9!}{k!}$ ways to fill the remaining $9-k$ cells with positive numbers.

Now consider the possibilities to fill a row.

Assume that a row starts from a zero. It there are $m$ remaining zeroes in the row then $0\le m\le 7$ and there are ${8\choose m}$ ways to place them in the row and $\tfrac {9!}{(m+1)!}$ ways to fill the remaining $8-m$ cells with positive numbers. This give us in total $N_0=\sum_{m=0}^7 {8\choose m}\tfrac {9!}{(m+1)!}=4596552$ possibilities to fill a row.

Assume that a row starts from a positive number. It there are $m$ zeroes in the row then $1\le m\le 8$ and there are ${8\choose m}$ ways to place them in the row and $\tfrac {8!}{m!}$ ways to fill the remaining $8-m$ cells with positive numbers. This give us in total $N_+=\sum_{m=1}^8 {8\choose m}\tfrac {8!}{m!}=1401409$ possibilities to fill a row.

In total, we have a bound

$N\le \sum_{k=1}^8 {9\choose k} \tfrac {9!}{k!} N_0^k N_+^{9-k}\approx 1.438\cdot 10^{64}$.

Again, this bound can be improved if we take into account that the rows are not independent but cannot contain a common positive number in the same column. But it seems this way leads to more complicted calculations and not a very big improvement.

Comment: THANKS a lot dear, I will try to come up with the answer (Soon if I can), then I will share it for verification. +50 :-)